# ASP.Net Core - Create Local IIS Website From 'Debug' Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

Can IIS server make a website from the debug folder?

My goal is to create a local website from the debug folder. 
When I make a change to the code, I just want to be able to build it and have the website be updated.

- [standard project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt9jP.png)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: That's almost impossible. See why https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the explanation on the [@Lex li blog](https://blog.lextudio.com/how-visual-studio-launches-iis-express-to-debug-asp-net-core-apps-d7fd3677e3c3), it seems like this can't be done in the near future.

For the ASP.Net project, you might find something here

- https://moriyama.co.uk/about-us/news/blog-automate-your-local-iis-development-environment/

Answer (score 0):

Sure - just create an Core Web Project.

You can start a debug IIS with e.g. IIS Express and your favourite, default browser.

[image: VS2019 Sniplet]